# Force a function to overwrite other actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I am trying to get some `contenteditable` elements working. Obviously this is incredibly easy with just a simple HTML5 attribute, but I want to be able to toggle the amount of elements with the attribute and also toggle the attribute itself. For example, my starting element is this `<article class="column contentEditable">` and then the class of `contentEditable` is used to toggle the `contenteditable` attribute. But because I am duplicating this element an amount of times based on what the user selects - I need to run the `.focus()` action as a function which is then called when some more `articles` are added. With me so far? Hope so.

Here is the jQuery I have so far (bearing in mind another function sets the class `contentEditable` to have the attribute `contenteditable`)

```
// content edittable
function makeEditable(action){  
$('.contentEditable').focus(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).prepend('<div class="toolbar" contenteditable="false">TEST</div>');
});
$('.contentEditable').blur(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).remove('.toolbar');
    alert('test');
});
}
```

To a certain extent this works perfectly, however because an `article` may have already been there when this DOM call was issued before, it means that it's running twice or more (depending on how many times I've changed the option in the select. How on earth can I get the function to only run once per item, i.e. not stack.

Hope this all makes sense, pretty difficult to explain.

Comment: I think that some HTML would help with what needs to be done here!

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening here is that you are calling the makeEditable function everytime the user is selecting an element to edit (if I understand your workflow right). If that's happening you're adding a new focus and blur event every time they do and that will cause the event to fire multiple times.

What I recommend is something like this:

```
function addElement(containerElement) {
    // containerElement is a string with the jQuery selector of the parent element
    var el = $('<article class="column contentEditable"></article>').appendTo(containerElement);
    el.focus(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).prepend('<div class="toolbar" contenteditable="false">TEST</div>');
    });
    el.blur(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).remove('.toolbar');
        alert('test');
    });
}

function toggleEditable(el) { 
    // here el is a string with the jQuery selector of the element
    $(el).toggleClass('contentEditable');
}
```

Comment: Sort of right. You are correct in saying that there is a new focus and blur effect added every time at the element and process them with `makeEditable`. I've fixed it now anyway, it was a simple case of having a `process` class on it to only run it once, each time the `.focus` is run it removes the `process` class. Thanks for having a pop, I probably didn't explain it too well.

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple case of having a `process` class on it to only run it once, each time the `.focus` is run it removes the `process` class. Pretty simple really, fresh eyes helped after a break. Thanks.